# How to change TCA configuration of `news` with `eventnews` is installed?

Tags: typo3

I am not able to fully change the TCA configuration of `news` with `eventnews` installed. The changes I do in my site configuration extension in `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php` are always overwritten by the changes configured in `eventnews`.

My site configuration TypoScript setup is included after `eventnews` TypoScript setup, of course, but this seems to be of no importance.

In my site configuration extension I configured a dependency to `eventnews` in the hope that this makes the `eventnews` TCA manipulation to be executed before mine. But this also had no effect.

I installed `tcabuilder` again with no effect. The `eventnews` TCA manipulation is always stronger.

The only way I found until now is to deactivate the `addToAllTCAtypes` calls in `EXT:eventnews/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php`. After this I can do what I am supposed to with the `news` TCA.

Is there a clean way to manipulate the `news` TCA with `eventnews` installed?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this mostly depends on the loading order. You should require / depend on news and eventnews in your sitepackage. This tells TYPO3 that they are needed before.

This means, add corresponding require to your sitepackage composer.json and add it as depend to your sitepackage ext_emconf.php.

This counts for most stuff, like TCA/TCA Override loading order etc.

And yes, if a extension is doing something in Overrides, you have to do it in Overrides too - combined with ensuring your extension runs after that extension.